# Subscribed topics

Tags: php, laravel

In my forum I'm showing all topics. It looks like this:

[image]

So a user can subscribe by clicking on the red hearth.

I'm loading the topics with this json:

```
{
  "forum": {
    "id": 1,
    "slug": "test",
    "name": "test",
    "description": "test",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
  },
  "topics": {
    "total": 6,
    "per_page": 5,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 2,
    "next_page_url": "http://forum.dev/api/forum/test?page=2",
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 5,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "1",
        "name": "1",
        "description": "1",
        "forum_id": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "slug": "2",
        "name": "1",
        "description": "1\t",
        "forum_id": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "slug": "1",
        "name": "1",
        "description": "1\t",
        "forum_id": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "slug": "1",
        "name": "1",
        "description": "1",
        "forum_id": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "slug": "1",
        "name": "1",
        "description": "1",
        "forum_id": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm returning that ^ like this: 
`$forum->topics()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(5);`

So how do I get a subscribe value on every topic object?

So like this:

```
 "data": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "1",
            "name": "1",
            "description": "1",
            "forum_id": 1,
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null,
            "subscribed": true
          },
```

I already made this on my `topic` model:

```
 /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function subscriptions()
    {
        return Topic::subscribedBy(Auth::user())->get();
    }
```

And it's working. But how do I send that ^ with every topic.

Comment: You should check out the `$appends` property

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an attribute (which is not present in the database) by creating an accessor.

```
public function getSubscriptionsAttribute()
{
    return Topic::subscribedBy(Auth::user())->get();
}
```

and then adding it to the `$append` property.

```
protected $appends = ['subscriptions'];
```

If you're using the `$visible` whitelist you might have to add it to that property too.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json) (Its all the way in the bottom.)

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Comment: But is this the good way? Because it does a lot of queries right now?

Comment: Well, you're using `paginate(5)` so i dont think you'll have performance issues, its quite possible that you can optimize it but thats up to you in the end :)